# Having trouble installing newest version of Python: make error?

Tags: python, c, compilation, makefile

I have Python 2.7 on my Fedora VM and I want to upgrade to Python 3.3.2. I did this:

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2
tar xf Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2
cd Python-3.3.2
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

And then tried

```
make
```

Only to get this error:

```
Objects/abstract.c:2281:20: error: variable 'countva' is uninitialized when
      used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
        Py_VA_COPY(countva, va);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
Include/pyport.h:875:37: note: expanded from:
#define Py_VA_COPY(x, y) Py_MEMCPY((x), (y), sizeof(va_list))
                                    ^
Objects/abstract.c:2278:20: note: initialize the variable 'countva' to
      silence this warning
    va_list countva;
                   ^
                    = NULL
1 error generated.
make: *** [Objects/abstract.o] Error 1
```

...what? How do I fix this? There shouldn't be something wrong with the Python installation file, should there?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the Python archive, it must be your environment.

I reproduced your exact steps on my system and it runs on my system. I think the `-Werror` switch is to blame. It will turn warnings into errors. What your compiler actually encounters is merely a warning.

Can you type in the same terminal `echo $CFLAGS` and post the output? On my system, this command will produce an empty line. Maybe you have some `CFLAGS` set in your `~/.bashrc`? Or maybe you do `source` a file in your `~/.bashrc` which sets `CFLAGS`?